# Rename function simultaneously in R

Tags: r, editor

I am developing R package, and wish to change the name of a function. How could I set the project up such that the function name can be changed simultaneously in all different files where the function is called? Should I use some particular editor, like Emacs? I am using RStudio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978753/refactoring-r-code-using-ess-r

Comment: that seems very helpful. Thanks @user4938503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that RStudio does not currently have the capability to do global variable renaming, q.v. [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200656093-Global-variable-renaming).

However, you will likely be safe just doing a find and replace in all files for the name of function followed by an open parenthesis.

For example, if your function is called `myFunc` and you want to rename it to `newFunc` then you can do the following replacement:

```
myFunc( -> newFunc(
```

Include the parenthesis to make sure that you are replacing only the function definition and calls, and not the string `myFunc` in some other context.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. That makes sense. If using Emacs, is there a quick way to achieve that?

Comment: As a last resort, if you have difficulty doing it in R, highlight your code, paste it into a text editor. Find and replace there.

Comment: @AaronZeng The answer to that is another question by itself, but you can [have a look here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html) at the Emacs documentation for how to do that.